# Generating Tables and Diagrams for Sentiment Analysis Using R

Tags: r, ggplot2, sentiment-analysis

Got a task in my work to simply analyse 30 reviews for 3 different products using R. So, I used the library `sentimentr` to do this and generate the web page with the good and bad words highlighted green and red respectively. That's fine. However, it also says on my sheet to:
"Generate Tables, Diagrams using R"
but I'm completely at a loss on what to even plot for this and how to plot for stuff like this.

The CSV file I'm using simply has 2 columns.
there are 30 rows, all divided by 10 for 3 products, so there's ID (1,2,3)

Don't know if this will help anything or not.

```
Reviews | ID
```

I've tried googling stuff like "ggplot for seniment analysis" but nothing helpful came up for me.

```
library(sentimentr)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)    
#reading the reviews
reviews = read.csv(file = "keyboard_reviews.csv", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(reviews)
reviews%>%
  mutate(revs = get_sentences(Reviews))%$%
  sentiment_by(revs,by=ID)%>%
  highlight()
```

Comment: You could help people help you by running dput(head(reviews)) and posting the output

Comment: This would be very broad even if we could see your data. What are you trying to plot? What type of plot are you trying to use? Diagrams of what? It seems like you're actually at the brainstorming stage of this project, not the debugging stage

Comment: https://www.tidytextmining.com/sentiment.html  http://jacobsimmering.com/2016/11/15/tidytext/